# Is functional component with arrow function handler better for performance then a class component with a handler bound in constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component with an arrow function event handler, that is considered bad practice, due to a need to re-create function every time component is rendered.

```
const SimpleQuestion = ({
  question,
  onChangeQuestionTitle
}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Question"
        value={question.title}
        onChange={(e) => onChangeQuestionTitle({
          id: question.id,
          title: e.target.value
        })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I cannot define external function for it, as it needs to access props, nor I see any advantage in this example:

```
const SimpleQuestion = ({
  question,
  onChangeQuestionTitle
}) => {

  const handleChangeQuestionTitle = (e) => {
    onChangeQuestionTitle({
      id: question.id,
      title: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Question"
        value={question.title}
        onChange={handleChangeQuestionTitle}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

To eliminate a need of arrow function I can use class component with constructor and bind(). Ex:

```
class SimpleQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)  
    this.onChangeQuestionTitle = this.onChangeQuestionTitle.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Question"
          value={question.title}
          onChange={this.onChangeQuestionTitle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChangeQuestionTitle(e) {
    this.props.onChangeQuestionTitle({
      id: question.id,
      title: e.target.value
    });
  }
}
```

Should I use class component or functional component with arrow function? Which is better from performance perspective?

PS: I am aware that I could export logic from Question component and do handler logic in parent container, but this question relates to performance topic.

Thanks

Comment: I feel as thought this question should be on [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

because you only need return some jsx and you don't care about the state of the component or any life cycle method the best option is the #2.

About your problem of creating unnecessary anonymous functions by passing a reference to the function to the `render()` method instead of the function itself method will be solved.

Comment: I would argue that #2 and #1 initialize handler function the same amount of times. The only difference is that in #2 handler is defined outside JSX, but still as component itself is a pure function, it is called every time, a rerender is needed. Agree that #3 example has state and lifecycles and that decrease the performance. Thats were the question arises, should I use class component without reinitialization of handler function, or functional component with reinitialization? Witch one is more efficient solution from performance point of view?

Comment: In this case, the best option is the second, it will be rendered faster, you don't need a class-based component because you don't care about the state of the component that's the work of the parent component and because you are returning just JSX functional components are the best option to use.

Answer (score -1):

Either the 2nd or 3rd methods would be preferred. As for which you should choose, I think that's a personal preference. I personally prefer the fat arrow syntax (#2) since you don't have to bind in the constructor. But in either case, you're solving the problem of creating unnecessary anonymous functions by passing a reference to the function (rather than the function definition) to the render().

Comment: As already mentioned in the previous answer comment, I would say 2nd creates array function the same amount of times as 1rst example does as component itself is pure function called each time rerender is needed. The question is - should I use class component with state and lifecycles (that decreases performance), or should I stick with functional component and handler function reinitialization each time component is rerendered? Which variant is of better performance and why?

Comment: I believe you're wrong about the second being the same as the first, but feel free to prove me wrong if you have a reference. I'll try to find something tomorrow that supports my claim

Comment: http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/container-components-and-stateless-functional-components-in-react/  "What about components with callbacks?" Says that "The only problem with this approach is that the handler function is recreated each time the DOM is rendered."

Comment: Yeah, I think that article is also wrong. If you read through [Handling Events - Official React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) you'll see that they propose three methods of binding your handlers. The only one they warn against is the inline fat arrow `<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>`, the warning being "he problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders"

Comment: 1st and 2nd examples from your source deal with class components, not functional component like the one in my example. Therefore you can use either binding in constructor or class field syntax to define a field in a class. When class component is used only render method is called during re-render, not the whole function as in case of functional component.